# Method GetProperties with BindingFlags.Public doesn't return anything

Tags: c#, reflection

Probably a silly question, but I couldn't find any explanation on the web.
What is the specific reason for this code not working? The code is supposed to copy the property values from the `Contact` (source) to the newly instantiated `ContactBO` (destination) object.

```
public ContactBO(Contact contact)
{
    Object source = contact;
    Object destination = this;

    PropertyInfo[] destinationProps = destination.GetType().GetProperties(
        BindingFlags.Public);
    PropertyInfo[] sourceProps = source.GetType().GetProperties(
        BindingFlags.Public);

    foreach (PropertyInfo currentProperty in sourceProps)
    {
        var propertyToSet = destinationProps.First(
            p => p.Name == currentProperty.Name);

        if (propertyToSet == null)
            continue;

        try
        {
            propertyToSet.SetValue(
                destination, 
                currentProperty.GetValue(source, null), 
                null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Both classes have the same property names (the BO class has a few other but they don't matter on initialization). Both classes have only public properties. When I run the example above, `destinationProps` **and** `sourceProps` have lengths of zero.

But when I expand the `GetProperties` method with `BindingFlags.Instance`, it suddenly returns everything. I would appreciate if someone could shed light on that matter because I'm lost.

Comment: If you wish to check `propertyToSet` against `null` you should not use `First` because it will throw a exception if it can not find an item which does not match the predicate. Use `FirstOrDefault` instead.

Comment: Just to save those who are paying as much attention as me to the difference between a Property and a Field, try GetFields(); whups.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

From the documentation of the [`GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) method:

> You must specify either BindingFlags.Instance or
>   BindingFlags.Static in order to get a
>   return.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. The reason for the question was why BindingFlags.Public does not return the public properties? Well I guess this is how the framework is working.

Answer (score 34):

This behaviour is because you must specify either Static or Instance members in the BindingFlags. BindingFlags is a flags enum that can be combined using `|` (bitwise or).

What you want is:

```
.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```